# How do i call the function twice properly .I do not get the desired output

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a function which draws line according to its parameters.So when I run the program for the first function call,I get the desired output.But when I call the function again  ,I do not get the line for the first function call.Instead I get the line for the second function call.Please help me on fixing this problem.

```js
function draw_vertical_line(width, height, linecolor, xpos, ypos) {
  $('.line').css({
    'width': width,
    'height': height,
    'background-color': linecolor,
    'left': xpos,
    'bottom': ypos,
    'position': 'absolute'
  });
}

draw_vertical_line(10, 500, '#357d35', 50, 100); //This line does not show
draw_vertical_line(10, 300, '#357d35', 300, 200); //This line shows
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are setting the CSS on the same element(s). So the second `draw_vertical_line` call overwrites the first.

Comment: You're not drawing (adding) a line, you're moving both lines each time, so the second move overwrites the first move.

Comment: @freedomn-m how can i add a line then?

Answer (score 2):

I hope I have been helpful

```js
        function draw_vertical_line(id, width, height, linecolor, xpos, ypos) {
            $('#'+id).css({
                'width': width,
                'height': height,
                'background-color': linecolor,
                'left': xpos,
                'bottom': ypos,
                'position': 'absolute'
            });
        }

        draw_vertical_line('line1', 10, 500, '#357d35', 50, 100);  
        draw_vertical_line('line2', 10, 300, '#357d35', 300, 200);
```

```html
    <div id="line1"></div>
    <div id="line2"></div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Optimized solution:

```js
function draw_vertical_line(lines) {
    for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        $('#wrap').append('<div class="line' + i + '"></div>');
        $('.line' + i).css({
            'width': lines[i][0],
            'height': lines[i][1],
            'background-color': lines[i][2],
            'left': lines[i][3],
            'bottom': lines[i][4],
            'position': 'absolute'
        });
    }
}

// List of lines
draw_vertical_line([
    [10, 500, '#357d35', 50, 100],
    [10, 300, '#357d35', 300, 200],
    [10, 200, '#cccccc', 100, 400],
    [10, 100, '#888888', 200, 500],
    [10, 300, '#222222', 600, 200]
]);
```

```html
    <div id="wrap"></div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Dude this was super duper helpful Thanks a lot mahn.I have another doubt hopefully you can answer this.What if i want to draw a lot of lines?How do i do it then? Is there a simple way for that or do i need to create multiple divs for it?

Comment: The way the code is currently written, you will need to create a div element for each line

Comment: I made an update. Try if this оptimized solution will be more convenient for you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `$(".line")` will always move the same line, so moving it once, then moving it again will only show the 2nd move.

To add new lines for each call, you can use

```
var div = $("<div>");
div.css({...});
$("body").append(div);
```

(or use whatever you're using as your "container" for the lines, this wasn't provided in the question, so using body here)

Alternatively, to save a variable and make use of jquery's chaining, you can use:

```
$("<div>").css({...}).appendTo("body");
```

Updated snippet:

```js
function draw_vertical_line(width, height, linecolor, xpos, ypos) {
  $("<div>").css({
    'width': width,
    'height': height,
    'background-color': linecolor,
    'left': xpos,
    'bottom': ypos,
    'position': 'absolute'
  }).appendTo('body');
}

draw_vertical_line(10, 500, '#357d35', 50, 100); 
draw_vertical_line(10, 300, '#357d35', 300, 120);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```